# Is there a way to display iPad Simulator fullscreen?

Tags: ios-simulator

does anyone know if there is some way (Applescript, secret .plist defaults setting...) to view an iPad simulator window on fullscreen (or borderless)? It would be very handy to show it on a second 1024x768 display at native resolution. The simulator's vertical size when in portrait is simply too high even for a fullHD monitor... the border is too thick and the window cannot be moved offscreen above the upper edge.

Comment: what if I didn't find a good answer yet?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe this will help?
https://plus.google.com/u/0/115321914207029284487/posts/gcqBJej1g4R

I guess, you can edit the frame.png to make the border even smaller. Maybe even nonexistent.

Comment: I edited the frame.png to be transparent and of size 1024x768. Now there is no option for an iPad simulator.

Comment: thanks, this is helpful. by the way, latest xcode eliminated the ipad frame so Apple itself solved this.

Comment: The link is unavailable

Answer (score 3):

1. Copy the Info.plist file that resides at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone Simulator.app/Contents/Resources/Devices/iPad.deviceinfo 
   onto your desktop. This folder is write protected and even with root enabled it crashes xcode if you try to edit it from here.
2. Double click on the file and edit the plist in Xcode  change the width variable to 1000 and the height variable to 1800. (I'm running this at 1366x768 and these settings worked. tweak if you need to)  Save it.
3. Copy your edited plist file and paste it back into the original folder and replace the existing file. Run your app. Rotate the device to landscape orientation.
4. Bask in the glow of a full screen window running ios.

Answer (score 0):

Selecting:

> Window -> Scale -> 100%

Will make twice bigger than default

Comment: I already did that and messed around with my display options, but its the best answer to the first half of the bounty request.  Thanks